# How do create an envelope via docusign api for another user's account?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to figure out how to create a envelope on behalf of another user's account within my domain.

I have been looking at the Send On Behalf Of...but several of the links in StackOverflow are broken.

I am using the Rest 2.1 Api, using C# and following a JWT automated examples.

I need to be able to create a envelope from a system account and make it look like joe@company.com sent the envelope to the recipients.

Thanks
jlimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to validate my domain in the Org Admin.  Once I did that, it started working great.

Answer (score 0):

You use the [OAuth JWT grant flow](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) to impersonate the other person.

"Send on behalf of" is part of the deprecated DocuSign Legacy authentication and is not supported for new eSignature REST applications.

Note that you'll also need to obtain that person's consent for your application to impersonate them. Or use Administrative Consent to proactively grant consent.

Comment: I have read this article.  I am looking code or an article with code on how I actually impersonate the user?

Comment: See the [C# example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp). It includes examples for both the JWT and Auth Code grant flows.